# "Subscript out of range" error for ListObject

Tags: excel, vba

I call a sub that select and convert ranges in multiple sheets into tables. It generates the tables and names them "SIS_1", "SIS_2" and so on. To use these tables in my current sub, I can declare and set table "SIS_1" in worksheets 3, but can't declare and set table "SIS_2" in worksheet 4 and so on. Does it have anything to do with the sheet code (highlighted in red)?

[image: IMG2]

I can't seem to find what the issue is. If I manually rename the "SIS_2" in excel into "SIS_x", then rename it back to "SIS_2", it seems to solve the issue and I can then declare the variable as usual. I don't understand why it's like that.

[image: IMG1]

Code i want to declare the ListObject

```
Public Sub ImportButton_Click()

    Dim totalSheets As Integer
    Dim startSheet As Integer, endSheet As Integer
    Dim masterSIS As ListObject, sourceSIS As ListObject
    Dim i As Integer

    Set masterSIS = Worksheets("MasterSIS").ListObjects("MasterSIS")

    totalSheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    Call importSheets([filePath])

    startSheet = totalSheets + 1
    endSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    Call convertToTable(startSheet, endSheet, "SIS")

    For i = 1 To endSheet - totalSheets
        Set sourceSIS = Worksheets(startSheet).ListObjects("SIS_" & i)
        Call appendTable(masterSIS, sourceSIS)
        startSheet = startSheet + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```

For anyone having similar problem. Hope this helps.

Found the solution here https://www.dingbatdata.com/2017/11/24/referencing-listobjects-with-vba/.

To declare LinkObject, you need to do it like this `Range("TableName").ListObject`.It seems that 'there will be a VBA error if the sheet changes it’s position'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195744/discussion-on-question-by-afdzal-yunus-subscript-out-of-range-error-for-listob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem with the table name wrongly generated from the loop code in previous sub. Fixed it and the error disappear.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030637/how-do-i-reference-tables-in-excel-vba) for a discussion of how to reference a `ListObject`. Also, each [`ListObject.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.name) is unique. Referencing a `ListObject` using a `Range` reference is a "hack," as explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28291086/9245853) to the linked question.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the info. Can you help explain to me the difference between `DisplayName` and `Name` property please?

Comment: I'll refer you to the [`DisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.displayname) and [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.name) documentation. From a quick test, it seems like Excel updates the `Name` if you update the `DisplayName`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I experienced a strange problem on Excel 365 and this thread is the first hit when you search for ListObjects + Out Of Range problem, so I hope this will help others looking for a solution.
PROBLEM: You select a group of cells in your workbook and assign it a name
[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erPj5.png)

If in your VBA code you refer to it as a Range Object like
`Me.cboEnterQuotesMarket.List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Requester").Range("tblMarket").Value` it is recognized correctly and populate the combobox with the values from the first column but if you want to populate the combobox with values from a different column, e.g. column N.2 and then use the ListObject like this

```
Me.cboEnterQuotesMarket.List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Requester").ListObjects("tblMarket").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Value
```

then you'll get the "Out of Range" error.
I used this code to find out the root cause

```
  Dim k As ListObject
   Dim s1 As Worksheet
   Dim t As Integer
   ' initializing integer variable
   ' traversing through each table and displaying each table name in a new cell
    For Each s1 In Worksheets
        Debug.Print s1.Name
      For Each k In s1.ListObjects
         Debug.Print k.Name
      Next k
   Next
```

You'll get as first the worksheet name and then all the table objects contained in that worksheet so I find out that the worksheet "Requester" doesn't contain any object even if the Range object was recognized to be valid for VBA.

SOLUTION:

1. I removed the reference to the group of cells within the "Formulas" -> "Name Manager" menu
2. I formatted the group of cells like a table with "Home" -> "Format as a table"

Ta daaah, problem solved